# HttpClient post returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm using Windows.Web.Http testing on Windows 8.1 store app (will do on Windows Phone 8.1 is passed this issue).

This is what I've done:

```cs
HttpMultipartFormDataContent formData = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
IStorageFolder aFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(imageFolder);
IStorageFile aFile = await aFolder.GetFileAsync("myImage.jpg");
IInputStream aStream = await aFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

formData.Add(new HttpStreamContent(aStream), "UploadFile", aFile.Name); // This is the problem. Remove this and HttpStreamContent captured well.
formData.Add(new HttpStringContent("some text"), "somename");
formData.Add(new HttpStringContent("another text"), "anothername");

HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();
aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Clear();
aclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36");
aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6,id;q=0.4");
aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate, sdch");

HttpResponseMessage aResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(aURI, formData);
aResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
aResponseHTML = await aResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Host reply error 500 Internal server error.
If I remove the file upload, no error. Data recorded fine with host's PHP script. 
I'm confident that the host's PHP script part works fine, same script works with HTML webform and another app developed using MS Visual Foxpro.

And tried to just send a file,

```cs
IStorageFolder aFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(imageFolder);
IStorageFile aFile = await aFolder.GetFileAsync("myImage.jpg");
IInputStream aStream = await aFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

IHttpContent aContent = new HttpStreamContent(aStream);
aContent.Headers.ContentType = new HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
aContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new HttpContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
{
    Name = "UploadFile",
    FileName = string.Format("\"{0}\"", aFile.Name) // found in a blog post that the name should be in quotes, else again error 500
};
HttpRequestMessage aRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, aURI);
aRequest.Content = aContent;

HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();
aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Clear();
aclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36");
aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6,id;q=0.4");
aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate, sdch");
aResponse = await aClient.SendRequestAsync(request);
```

This time, got an OK.
Failed at host. PHP $FILES array contains nothing.
the PHP script used to detect the uploaded file:

```php
if (isset($_FILES["UploadFile"]["name"])) { ....
```

Comment: Do you have Fiddler traces?

Comment: Today is my first day with Fiddler. Which portion from Fiddler should I show?

Comment: @kiewic Fiddler screen capture [link](http://mnh.my/data/upload/Fiddler_HttpRequestMessage.png)
This is from when I'm sending just the file using HttpRequestMessage.

Comment: Also, can you try replacing `new HttpStreamContent(aStream)` with `new HttpStringContent("foo")` to see if the stream is the problem or the headers?

Comment: In the first request, changing `HttpStringContent(aStream)` to `HttpStringContent("foo")`. I got a 200-Ok from the server and all value reads fine in the PHP code. The first request works if without the `HttpStreamContent`. For the second request, [link]http://mnh.my/data/upload/Fiddler_HttpRequestMessage2.png

Comment: The first request what I actually want to use, using the `HttpMultipartFormDataContent()`. Fiddler capture [link]http://mnh.my/data/upload/Fiddler_HttpRequestMessage3.png

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your request. What version of PHP are you using? You can find the version using `phpversion()`

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the request. One more option is you compare the failing Fiddler traces with some working Fiddler traces (you mentioned Web form works fine).

Comment: PHP version is 5.3.28 (its beyond my control) Will indeed compare the two Fiddler traces and seek the meaning. First glance, lots of differences and read more on the significance of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

### multipart/form-data

In you first request, you are sending a `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` request that is composed of smaller parts with headers and body. See [here for more information](http://monkeyweekend.com/2014-10-23/how-to-send-text-json-or-files-using-httpclient-postasync/). That should work with `$_FILES`.

You can use the following PHP script to validate data is received:

```
<?php
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

I used PHP 5.6.9 and it works fine.

### image/png or any other single file POST

In your second request, you are sending a `Content-Type: image/png`, your file is be the whole request body, `$_FILES` will not help in this case, you need to read all the request like this:

```
<?php
    $myFile = @file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```